# Detecting "first-child" of a "column box"

Tags: css, css-selectors, multiple-columns

I have a Multi-column layout. In the example below, I have 3 columns because I want to compare the vertical-align between the image and the paragraphs.

https://jsfiddle.net/09L7e5rs/1/

I have reset the margin and padding of the paragraph and only added padding-bottom, This way I normally align the paragraphs and other elements to the top. So far so good.

```
p {padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* Reset */

p {
line-height: 1.5em;
padding-bottom: 1em;}
```

When I am adding an image, I need to add some space to the paragraph after it. (First part of the fiddle) I am using:

```
img+p {
padding-top: 1em;}
```

The result is ok and looks like this

[image]

The problem comes when a paragraph after this image is in the next column. (To force this case on the paragraph I am adding a break-inside: avoid. The second part of the fiddle)

[image]

**Is there a way to detect this paragraph as a first-child of this [column box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/#column-box)?**

That way I could add a padding-top:0 in that case. (I guess not at least in CSS. I hope I do not need Javascript, probably to measure the distance to the parent's top border)

---

Edited: I am not adding paddings to the images, because on my template the vast majority of images need padding:0. This question is very specific about these "anonymous fragmentation containers".

I can work around this in several ways. Adding a specific class for the particular image, etc. But for now I want to avoid that.

Comment: You could use a `padding-bottom` on any child of the parent. Meaning both the `<img>`(s) and the `<p>`s. That results in the same space between paragraphs, but it would never end up offsetting at the top.

Comment: Thank you @Raxi. I added a small edit on the specificity of the case. And I think there is no "previous sibling selector" to add the style to the image when is followed by a paragraph.

Comment: edit: Sorry, just read the relevant bit ; you can work around this, i'll post it below

Comment: Yes, the majority of cases. This particular case Is the least common. I could work around it in a lot of ways, for example adding a span, or a div. Or adding a particular class to the specific paragraph. But for now, I want to keep the style sheet, and mainly the HTML code super clean :) But as I like a lot exploring what CSS selectors and these HTML "phantom containers", I want to explore this case first.

Comment: Yea, my initial idea was to use the `::after` pseudo selector on `:first-child`, giving it a margin or padding or height or w/e. But i forgot `::after` isn't available for `<img>`.